# How find whole words in tkinter text widget and not strings part of a word

Tags: python, tkinter

My present code -

```
def find():
    
    #remove tag 'found' from index 1 to END
    text.tag_remove('found', '1.0', END)
    
    #returns to widget currently in focus
    s = edit.get()
    if s:
        idx = '1.0'
        while 1:
            #searches for desired string from index 1
            idx = text.search(s, idx, nocase=1,
                            stopindex=END)
            if not idx: break
            
            #last index sum of current index and
            #length of text
            lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(s))
            
            #overwrite 'Found' at idx
            text.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
            idx = lastidx
        
        #mark located string as red
        text.tag_config('found', foreground='red')
    edit.focus_set()
```

The problem is  this-
if I need to find `"hell"`
it will also highlight hell in `"hello"`
But I need to only detect whole words . A simple solution  can be searching for `" hell "`
but it will not work in a string like this
`"hell is my hell"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a regular expression, and anchor the search string with a word start and word end constraint. To use a regular expression search, set the `regexp` parameter to `True` when calling `search` and surround the target string with the word start constraint (`\m`) and the word end constraint (`\M`).

Here's the few lines that need to change:

```
pattern = f"\\m{s}\\M"
while 1:
    idx = text.search(pattern, idx, nocase=1,
                      stopindex=END, regexp=True)
```

It's important to know that the text widget uses the underlying Tcl interpreter's regular expression engine which is slightly different than what python uses. A full description can be found on the [re_syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) man page.

Also, your own definition of "word" might be different than tcl's definition of "word". If that's the case you can use whatever pattern you want in lieu of the built-in word constraints.

Comment: I can't tell how much you helped me! Thanks a lot brother works perfectly